# Pronunciation spelling in "Ejpaña"

Tags: ortografía, españa, pronunciación, dialectos

I know of no phonological process in any dialect that, before a bilabial plosive, converts/accommodates the interdental fricative in the velar larynx. Therefore, I would like to know what the spelling *E**j**paña* represents, or some audio/video where such pronunciation occurs.

Comment: It's an internet typo: España. https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1BUT_e0xziFbuGDkAZ8L5rCZK9fo&hl=en_US&ll=40.745885488863%2C-1.7717095000000023&z=6

Comment: No, Lambie, it's not a typo. It's a relatively common way of mocking a Madrid accent, as mentioned in Roberto's answer, and it's often spelt like that in Internet forums in a derisive way by (especially) Catalan or Basque nationalists. So, a nationalist who dislikes the idea of Spain 
as a nation state will write things like "Son cosas de Ejpaña", "Esa gentuza estaba cantando 'yo soy ejpañol, ejpañol'" and things like that.

Comment: @Lambie, as Ángel José Riesgo states, it's not a typo and yes, it's a common way of mocking Madrid accent, but it's not restricted or even particularly associated, to Catalan or Basque nationalists, but rather with anyone who dislikes the chauvinism or the jingoism. You can listen to it anywhere in Spain.

Comment: @NunoAndré Yes, right. Except what I gave as a link is a typo. So, in fact, there are three possibilities: Typo (in the link I provided), old writing **and** maybe mocking the northern Spain accent, depending on context. The OP provided ZERO context.

Answer (score 3):

Las razones y el medio donde lo ha leído pueden ser diversos y por tanto dependerá de ello para concretar una mejor respuesta. A falta de saber donde lo leyó o escucho, aquí le dejo algunas de las motivaciones que pueden haber inspirado ese sonido;

1.- Como ha apuntado "lambie", puede ser un error tipográfico.

2.- Como ha apuntado "sumélico", la "s" puede convertirse en "h" con aspiración y tener sonido de "j".

3.- Algunos nacionalistas vascos y catalanes escriben o pronuncian la palabra "ejpaña" por no querer pronunciar "España".

4.- Ciertos autores han querido pronunciar la "S" de España como una "X", de esta manera "**Expaña**", se pronunciaría como la "X" de México (Méjico), ya que durante un tiempo la "X" tomó en español, entre otros, el sonido de "J", como en México (Méjico) o Texas (Tejas). Entonces "Expaña" (Ejpaña).

[image]

[image]

*La venda, la balanza y la Ejpá 1935
Matín Gómez Palacio 1893 - 1970 México*

5.- Otros autores como Salvador Freixedo han escrito libros políticos de parodias y sátiras , en donde claramente en el prólogo declara que es un "*Un libro de política y literalmente incorrecto*", de esta manera, Freixedo juega con la pronunciación de la palabra España.

[image]

[image]

6.- También en la actualidad algunos quieren imitar los textos y formas antiguas del español, donde la palabra "España" o "españoles" aparecía escrita de manera algo distinta y como le es imposible encontrar esa especie de "S larga" en el teclado actual, escriben una "j" intentando de este modo asemejarse al original.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.meneame.net/m/actualidad/enfado-sector-construccion-insistencia-contratar-extranjeros/c151#c-151

Comment: Siempre crei que era un forma de mofarse del acento madrileño, de las formaciones politicas de derechas, o ambas cosas a la vez. Algo asi como [este comentario](https://www.eldebate.com/educacion/20220816/doble-rasero-alegria-tolerancia-ante-desmanes-catalanes-vascos-e-intransigencia-ayuso_54701.html) de otro sitio: «Independentsia para Madri! Y que se imponga el idioma madrileño en las clases, nada de decir "España" o "es que", ahora en Madri diremos orgullosos "Ejpaña" y "ej que"!»

Answer (score 2):

*España* would only have an interdental fricative [θ] in an accent with *ceceo.*

More typically, it would have an alveolar sibilant [s].

But in many accents of Spanish, /s/ at the end of a syllable is turned into [h] (this can change further, like turning into aspiration on the following consonant or just being lost in some cases). See [Debuccalization of /s/ to [h]](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/673/debuccalization-of-s-to-h), [Fonético específico en una variación centroamericana del sonido /s/ en los fines de sílabas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26581)

The letter *j* can also be pronounced as [h] (a glottal fricative, rather than a velar fricative) in some accents. My guess is that the spelling *Ejpaña* represents [ehpana] or a similar pronunciation.

It could be a typo, but the letters S and J are fairly far apart on the keyboard. Also, the repeated use of J instead of syllable-final S in this headline ("[Ejpaña no ej madrajtra, ej madre](https://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/2005-06-01/juan-carlos-girauta-iejpana-no-ej-madrajtra-ej-madrei-5205141/)", Juan Carlos Girauta, *Libertad Digital*) doesn't seem plausibly explained as a typo, and the first paragraph comments:

> Acabo de oír a Javier Somalo reproducir esta impresionante frase, con todas sus jotas...

Comment: https://www.meneame.net/m/actualidad/enfado-sector-construccion-insistencia-contratar-extranjeros/c151#c-151

Answer (score 2):

The replacement of the "s" sound by a "j" before a consonant is usually identified with people from the Madrid region. "Ej que" instead of "es que" is an expression that immediately identifies the speaker as being from that part of Spain.

https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/60470/WRIGHT-DISSERTATION-2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

https://madridsecreto.co/acento-madrileno-no-existe/

https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/del-ejque-y-otras-claves-para-identificar-el-habla-de-madrid/

As a video sample check this one, between 4:00 and 4:05 he pronounces it twice "***loj que más mandan.... sea máj concreto***":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5gpShj8f0A&ab_channel=La8Palencia